# How do I join two networks using two lan cards?

Tags: linux, networking

I have multiple servers with 2 LAN cards each.

I want to use their second LAN cards to connect them to each other using a network switch.

My question is - How do I 'join' the networks together on the OS level, using the private network ip range for the second connection.

Basically I want every server to connect to the Internet normally, except when using the 10.x.x.x ip range, in which case the local connection is to be used.

Comment: Have you found that they don't do this normally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The server's routing table will naturally prefer directly connected routes.

Say that `eth0` has IP address 192.168.0.10/24, and `eth1` has 10.0.0.10/8, with default gateway only set on `eth0`. Then `eth1` will be used for packets with a destination of 10.0.0.0/8, and `eth0` for everything else but localhost.